# Example Uses of Action Helpers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Action Helpers are recommended in general over extending `Zend_Controller_Action`.

Looking at some of the applications you've built recently, what did you use Action Helpers for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common for my app:

- redirector
- static cache
- service loader
- messenger

Edit: I forgot to mention the switchers:

- ajaxContext
- contextSwitcher

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

> Action Helpers allow developers to
>   inject runtime and/or on-demand
>   functionality into any Action
>   Controllers that extend
>   Zend_Controller_Action. Action Helpers
>   aim to minimize the necessity to
>   extend the abstract Action Controller
>   in order to inject common Action
>   Controller functionality.

**Some useful Links:**

- [Use Zend Framework Action Helpers to Reduce PHP Code Redundancy](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/zend-action-helpers/Jason_Gilmore091410.php3)
- [Action Helpers in Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350)
- [Using Action Helpers in Zend Framework](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/using-action-helpers-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: I think you got the down vote because he asks for examples not for an explanation of what Action Helpers are.

Comment: @Skelton: I explained because I found this in his question: `what did you use Action Helpers for?`.  I give Example Link because I found this in his question: `Looking at some of the applications`